# Apache - How to limit Content-Type header length to avoid CVE-2014-0050?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, httpd, ddos

On Thursday a **DoS** problem with **Tomcat** was announced in a Tomcat mailing list (["[SECURITY] **CVE-2014-0050** Apache Commons FileUpload and Apache Tomcat DoS"](http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/www-announce/201402.mbox/%3C52F373FC.9030907@apache.org%3E)).

An attacker seems to be able to cause an infinite loop by sending an overlong `content-type` header when uploading files (if the Servlet 3.0+ upload capability is used in the web application), as far as I understood the message at first glance.

If someone operates their Tomcat servers behind Apache httpd servers (using AJP and mod_jk), what could one do to implement the recommendation *"Limit the size of the Content-Type header to less than 4091 bytes"*?

Of course, as soon as a bugfix release is available (through the download page or Linux distribution specific package repositories), one should update. No question. But at the moment the [currently available Tomcat version 7.0.50](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) seems to be still affected.

But what could one do as a quick defensive measure, until a fixed release is available?

(Without having to ...

- uninstall current Tomcat packages (installed from package repository),
- build the versions manually from the sources (SVN),
- deploy them manually (without `apt-get` or `aptitude`),
- later uninstall all the manually built stuff again in favor of comfortably updateable versions from the package repository)

Are there ways similar to the temporary work-arounds for this topic: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CVE-2011-3192 ?

Back then, one could use **mod_headers**, **mod_setenvif** or **mod_rewrite** to deal with the problem. Are there similar Apache httpd tricks to keep the malformed *multipart* upload requests away from the downstream Tomcat server?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! - For all Tomcat users who find this question: In the meantime, the Tomcat team published a new release (7.0.52), which fixes __CVE-2014-0050__: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apache (including a modified version from Shane; reading the [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-124) i wouldnt bet the length of `Content-String` is always < 129

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} "multipart\/form-data;(\s*)boundary=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3000}"
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /405.html [R=301,L]

# modified 
SetEnvIf Content-Type ^.{3000,}$ bad-content-type=1
RequestHeader unset Content-Type env=bad-content-type
```

nginx (did not found a way around if() )

```
server {
  ...
  if ($http_content_type ~* "multipart\/form-data;(\s*)boundary=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3000}" ) {
  return 403; 
  }
  ...

}
```

Comment: It would be more consistent to use this hack:  `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /405.html [R=405,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work.  The CVE announce says 4091 bytes, but the [accidental disclosure](http://markmail.org/message/kpfl7ax4el2owb3o) email seems like the devs are leaning toward 70-128 bytes as a limit.  Let's go with 128, but can be adjusted as needed:

```
SetEnvIf Content-Type ^.{129,}$ bad-content-type=1
RequestHeader unset Content-Type env=bad-content-type
```

Just unsetting the header (instead of 403'ing the request completely) is probably being unnecessarily gentle with the apparent attack requests, but this should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! One aspect I was thinking about: The affected HTTP POST multipart requests can contain several `Content-Type` headers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/913749/2052584 Will the given workaround only match the very first occurrence in the HTTP request header (`Content-Type: multipart/form-data;`) but not the individual `Content-Type` headers of the parts / files?

Comment: @MrSnrub It should be matching the combined version of the header where each copy is joined into a comma-separated list; it'll be checking the combined total length of all copies of the header.